How does 'Automatic Suspend' determine the computer is idle?
I'm running an Ubuntu 24.04 setup on a Dell Precision 3630 Tower.
I use the computer as the host for my remote-development for JetBrains tools such as PyCharm.
In this case, the PyCharm app runs on my Windows machine but all the files / code / data etc. is actually sitting on the Ubuntu server. If I open up the terminal console on PyCharm, it's opening up a terminal on my Ubuntu server.
To save a bit of power, I also have Automatic Suspend setup on the Ubuntu server (configured via the GUI) and it's set to suspend after 1 hour of inactivity.
My issue is that my server will go into 'suspend' mode while I'm running and actively working on PyCharm projects.
Is there a way that I can tell 'Automatic Suspend' to consider certain processes to mean that the server is still actively being used?

You mention Ubuntu Server, but then mention a GUI??  Ubuntu Server is text only and does not include a GUI.  If you've added a GUI to a server system, depending on the packages added, you may have turned the system into a Desktop system, thus desktop rules apply (ie. mouse/keyboard movement).  What exactly are you running, as Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS has no GUI/graphical interface, no desktop etc.

Sorry, yes running Ubuntu Desktop with GUI (using a HDMI emulator) but primarily acting over SSH as one would with a server.

gsetting set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 9999

On a desktop computer, "activity" probably means local keyboard/mouse interaction; this may not apply to remote terminal sessions.
Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714803/ubuntu-22-04-is-sleeping-even-though-i-changed-the-power-settings-so-it-shouldn
